# How do I call this type of UI widget?

Tags: gui-design, design-patterns, interface

[image]

I designed this but what would be a proper name? Data-table, info bar, list?
When you click on each item of the list, it displays information on the right side. Programming wise it was not done as a data-table TH

Comment: How about "**Product dashboard**".

Answer (score 6):

This is a list (or data table) with an inspector panel on the right side.

It is a variation of a master / detail pattern.

Comment: +1. This is a table with a inspector panel. Couldn't have said it easier.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say list or table, but as you have column headings, I'd go with table.

You might want to see how design systems from well known companies describe them:
https://adele.uxpin.com/

Answer (score 2):

I would call the right pane "Details Pane".

Alternatively it can be called "Preview Pane", if it is only showing a subset of information for the item and there's another view with the full info. Preview is the term used in Windows Explorer and OSX Finder.

Comment: I agree with the answer. It's called Preview Pane which is present in outlook, Gmail. Wherein on one side, you have the list of options and on the other side, you have the preview of the selected option/tab. They give you the ability to view content and list of options side by side. For reference:
[https://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-get-the-new-gmail-preview-pane/](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-get-the-new-gmail-preview-pane/)